# Can the IndexedDb file location be a shared location

Tags: indexeddb, progressive-web-apps

I have a progressive web app that employees use in disconnected mode.  They scan inventory items in the shop, the app searches local data to find the scanned item(indexedDb datastore with about 1/2 million records).

This data is synchronized fully to monthly, and deltas daily thru api calls.

After scanning multiple items, the laptop is connected and the scans are uploaded.  This is working, but now multiple people are sharing the same computer, each with their own login.  This required each user to have their own indexedDb.  It is my understanding that the indexedDb file is stored under the user/AppData folder per user.

Is there any way to share the same indexedDb instance between users on the same machine?  Or are my options to either have an instance per user or use a different technology.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Looks like someone asked a similar question, but from the exact opposite end: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067267/indexeddb-per-multiple-users. Maybe Chrome changed how this works within the last 4 years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, this will not work. It's not quite what you described:

> the indexedDb file is stored under the user/AppData folder per user

More specifically, IndexedDB data is stored in the browser profile folder. For some browsers, there is not a one-to-one relationship between users and profiles. Usually this distinction is not important, but it could provide an answer to your problem!

The general idea is:

1. Create a profile that you will use for this app.
2. Figure out the command to start a browser using that profile (pass it in via the command line, and/or use a symlink if the profile folder must be within a specific folder per user).
3. Have your users use that command to open the browser to interact with your app, otherwise they will not be able to access the shared IndexedDB database.

Obviously this is a horrible hack, but I think it should be possible to make it work.

Comment: This "horrible hack" still works for me. Thanks.